# How to run my node.js application through /etc/rc.local?

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi

I want to run a node application from my raspberry pi. The application is supposed to start on boot.

I have included the following lines in /etc/rc.local (before exit 0) :

```
    cd /home/pi/PPBot
    node bot.js > dev/null &
```

I first navigate to the correct folder and then run the bot from there. However the node application is not running when I reboot my raspberry pi. So it seems that rc.local is not executed or unable to execute the lines I provided.

I am looking for a solution so that the application will run at boot.

Answer (score 0):

save this

```
[Unit]
Description=Node JS Script Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /path/to/hello_env.js
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

to /etc/systemd/system/ as `nodescript.service`
`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
`sudo systemctl start nodescript`
if it worked, make it startup on boot 
`sudo systemctl enable nodescript`

Comment: Thanks I tried this. However when I run `sudo systemctl start nodescript` it tells me that it failed. `Failed to start Node JS Script Service`

Comment: i'm sorry for the late answer, but the solution should be `chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/nodescript.service`

Comment: Thanks again for the response. However it still doesn't seem to be working correctly, nothing happens when I run `sudo systemctl start nodescript`. After running `systemctl status nodescript.service` I get the following output:
[details why it failed](https://ibb.co/TwHpBzH)
[nodescript.service](https://ibb.co/0MX78Wx)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but did you ever find a fix? I'm having the same issue as @K.Tilman

Comment: now as you respond to this old post i totally forgot to mention, that your script needs to have the execution flag of course `chmod +x /path/to/hello_env.js`

Answer (score 0):

The examples I 've seen (like [this one](https://weworkweplay.com/play/raspberry-pi-nodejs/)) used

```
cd /home/pi/PPBot
node bot.js < dev/null &
```

instead of

```
cd /home/pi/PPBot
node bot.js > dev/null &
```

Note the `<` instead of the `>`. As you can see [here](http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/command-basics-reference), the `<` redirects the Standard In (stdin), while the `>` redirects the Standard Output (stdout). And as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27958),

> `< /dev/null` is used to instantly send EOF to the program, so that it doesn't wait for input (`/dev/null`, the null device, is a special file that discards all data written to it, but reports that the write operation succeeded, and provides no data to any process that reads from it, yielding EOF immediately). `&` is a special type of command separator used to background the preceding process.

Since you havent used `< dev/null`, maybe your program is stuck and waits for some input. The `&` at the end makes your program run in the background. Try to not include it and see if your Rasberry Pi is still booting. If not, you know that your programs runs continously and blocks further booting; when you used the `&` sign, your program just failed in a separate process. In this case changing the `>` to `<` should help because your programs doesn't wait for input.

If the above doesn't work, update your question with the specific error message. You can view the boot log by using the command `dmesg` (display message).

Answer (score 0):

In this case when you
`cd /home/pi/PPBot`
you are no longer in the root directory so when you run
`node bot.js > dev/null &`
it is looking for the `dev` folder at `/home/pi/PPBot/dev`

You will need to add a leading `/` to ensure it is accessing `/dev`

change

`node bot.js > dev/null &`

to

`node bot.js > /dev/null &`